# Ajax call effect Laravel View pagination

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I have a Laravel project which in userlist.blade.php i have it display the users list which work fine but i used select field to limit the pagination to different value and with a help from Nitish Kumar here in Stackoverflow i was able to get the value chosen from select field but i try to know how i can get the value to effect the current pagination but i can't not understand how things work Also the index in the loop which i used to display user increment number not work good with pagination so i really need help here to understand how things work. please ?

userlist.blade.php
https://codeshare.io/2KoB4X

UsersController
https://codeshare.io/G8rzjB

Script.js
https://codeshare.io/5o0pWM

Routes
https://codeshare.io/a3opmm

**Edit 1:**
An example for what i'm looking for in the link below there is Data Table where you can select Show number of entries to display the result in the table
https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/pages/tables/data.html

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**.

Comment: I'd suggest to use [Yajra Datatable package](https://datatables.yajrabox.com/) which allows you to use [jQuery datatble](https://datatables.net/) with server side processing. It will solve the issue with dynamic pagination and will add more functionality in your user list table.

Comment: @apokryfos my question is how a control the pagination using select to display a limited number of users in the table par page.

Comment: @ManishVerma Thanks i will test this how later since i will need more to add but i for now i hope i can find an answer to my code

Answer (score 0):

This is the current code i have

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#issueinput5').on('change', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url:'/lists/user',
        method:'POST',
        headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
        data:{'pageinateData':$('#issueinput5').val(),},
        success:function(d){
          console.log(d)
        }
   });
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-5">
    <div class="col-md-1">Show</div>
    <div class="col-md-2"><select id="issueinput5" name="priority" class="form-control" 
    data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="top" data-title="Priority">
      <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
    </select></div>
    <div class="col-md-1">entries</div>
</div>
<div class="table-responsive pl-1 pr-1">
    <table class="table table-bordered mb-0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Full Name</th>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>User Type</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach ($users as $user)
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">{{ $loop->index + 1 }}</th>
                <td>{{ $user->fullname }}</td>
                <td>{{ $user->username }}</td>
                <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
                <td>
                    @foreach( $roles as $role ) {{ $user->role_id == $role->id ? $role->name : ''}}                         @endforeach
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="{{ route('dUseInfo', [$user->id]) }}"><button type="button" 
                    class="btn mr-0 mb-0 btn-outline-primary btn-sm"><i class="icon-settings2"></i>                         </button></a>
                    <button type="button" class="btn mr-0 mb-0 btn-outline-primary btn-sm" 
                    data-toggle="modal" data-target="#iconModal" data-user-id="{{ $user->id }}">
                    <i class="icon-trash3"></i></button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```